# CakePHP - accepting arguments from the URL

Tags: php, api, cakephp

I am working with an external API that needs to call a URL in the form:

```
http://mysite/ussd/start?msisdn=123123123&provider=MTN
```

Where start is the controller method.

I am fully aware of the format in sending parameters like this:

```
http://mysite/ussd/start/msisdn=123123/test=2
```

but the other company is unable to change the format that they call the URL in.

How can I set Cake up to accept parameters in the format above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$this->params['url']['msisdn']` and `$this->params['url']['provider']` here. You can read about [Controller parameters](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Controllers.html#url) from cake manuals.

Comment: Thanks - I also found that I can use: $this->params['query'];

Comment: @andy: always specify which cake version you are using. I recently added `$this->request->query('provider')` for example as a neat getter method for cake2.3 and above.